# Using an Inner join select statement

Tags: sql, t-sql, inner-join

I am fairly new to SQL. I have created an inner join between 2 tables and further created some where clauses to pull out the appropriate data. As I understand it I have used an inner join to connect 2 tables. What I am trying to do now is connect my resultant select query to another table. How would I do this?

```
SELECT  
t.[Type]



from [MITS].[dbo].[monster] t 

inner join (

SELECT [MITS].[dbo].[BROKERTABLE].[BrokerID]
      ,[MITS].[dbo].[CustomerRates].[MPAN_ID]
      ,[MITS].[dbo].[BROKERTABLE].[Commission_Rate]
      ,[MITS].[dbo].[BROKERTABLE].[Rate_From]
      ,[MITS].[dbo].[BROKERTABLE].[Rate_To]
      ,[MITS].[dbo].[CustomerRates].[From_Date]
      ,[MITS].[dbo].[CustomerRates].[To_Date]


  from [MITS].[dbo].[CustomerRates]

   Inner Join [MITS].[dbo].[BROKERTABLE]
  on [MITS].[dbo].[BROKERTABLE].[MPAN_ID] =
  [MITS].[dbo].[CustomerRates].[MPAN_ID]

  where

  [MITS].[dbo].[CustomerRates].[To_Date] <=
  [MITS].[dbo].[BROKERTABLE].[Rate_To]

   and
   convert(datetime,'01/11/2015',103)
   between convert(datetime,[MITS].[dbo].[CustomerRates].[From_Date],103) 
   and convert(datetime,[MITS].[dbo].[CustomerRates].[To_Date],103)

   ) d on t.MITID  = d.MPAT_ID
```

Comment: Have you considered including your existing query into your question?, and the name of the table and the column(s) that would be used in joining that extra table? *In short, your question is absent any details, so the answers (if any) would also be absent details.*

Comment: There are `INNER`,`LEFT`,`RIGHT`,`FULL` AND `CROSS` joins see [Visual Guide to Joins](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33052/Visual-Representation-of-SQL-Joins)

Comment: You can join as many tables using as many join types (e.g. inner) as you'd like. Inner join means only where a match can be found from both tables will a record be returned in your results. Adding another inner join to a third table would force this restriction across another table

Comment: Are the `CustomerRates` columns `From_Date` and `To_Date` char or varchar? why are you converting them to datetime?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add extra table into existing query: guess 1

```
select *
from atable a
inner join btable b on a.somecol = b.somecol
inner join extra_table t on a.somecol = t.somecol and b.somecol = t.somecol2
```

Add existing query to a table, method 1

```
select *
from extra_table t
inner join (
            your existing query here
           ) d on t.somecol = d.somecol
```

Add existing query to a table, method 2

```
select *
from (
            your existing query here
      ) d 
inner join extra_table t on d.somecol = t.somecol
```

Comment: Hi thanks for this, why when I replace the * with the column names I get an error stating can't be bound?

Comment: if you have followed my examples 2 or 3, the top level select clause would use only the alias `d.` for every column, if you have used any other alias it would fail.

Comment: But the issue is that I'm bringing back every column of the extra table rather than just the columns I want because I'm using select *

Comment: Very well stick to what works, I can't see your code so I  can't do much to fix it.

Comment: I will copy and paste give me 30 mins

Comment: By the way you haven't even revealed which option you followed so i am literally blind as to the problem (s)

Comment: Add it to your question DON'T use a comment

Comment: just updated the question. What i am showing works, however i bring back all the columns within [MITS].[dbo].[monster]

Comment: `why when I replace the * with the column names I get an error stating can't be bound?` you now have an aliases `t` and `d` in that select clause you will need to prefix any column name with one of those. e.g. `t.*, d.Rate_From, d.Rate_To`

Comment: I have added in t.[MITS].[dbo].[monster].[Type] but that hasnt worked, what i am doing wrong?

Comment: i have modified the query to just read t.[Type] as it appears i have already defined the table as t. which prefixes the column called Type. However now i only bring back the column called [Type]. But removing this and replacing it with a * brings back all the columns from the extra table..can you advise?

Comment: Not sure what you are asking. * will return every column from all tables. t.* will return only the columns from that table. [] is needed if the name is a reserved word or a string containing a space or other special character.  A common problem is that 2 or more tables share colunn names. ID is the classic example. If you need id from 2 tables you have to alias at least one `select t.id , x.id as xid` so each column ultimately has unique names in the result. Enough?